# Spring boot does not fail for missing @Value property when it comes from custom starter

Tags: spring-boot

When using custom starter:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:monitoring.properties")
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "xxx.monitoring.enabled",
                       havingValue = "true",
                       matchIfMissing = true)
public class MonitoringAutoConfiguration {

    private static final String XXX_MONITORING_SERVICE_NAME = "${xxx.monitoring.service-name}";

    @Bean
    public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsCommonTags(@Value(XXX_MONITORING_SERVICE_NAME)
                                                                            String serviceName) {
        return registry -> registry.config()
                                   .commonTags("application", serviceName);
    }
```

When running integration test from within starter and not setting the value, I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'xxx.monitoring.service-name' in value "${xxx.monitoring.service-name}
```

When the starter kicks off in the main project it doesn't crash it as I expect it to, but resolves the value to :

**"${xxx.monitoring.service-name}"** instead, is that intentional? In my case I'd prefer the app to crash rather than corrupt metrics with this unresolved, can add validation but this behavior is surprising, I was aware of config properties, but not this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because the profile with which application spins up for integration test and main project is different

Comment: sorry not sure what it has to do with profile. There isn't any set for integration so it's 'dev' then, the application is ran wtih dev as well, but I didn't set the property for both integration test and application yet they behave differently.